# Does the question reflected in the URL change when a question title is edited?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, seo

I'm assuming that the end of the URL associated with a question is changed whenever a title is edited... is this correct?

Does the original URL link to the edits page?

If so, what are the implications to SEO for the site, since Google is considered the home-page of SO?  Is this deemed an acceptable trade-off, since edits will most likely take place early in the lifespan of the question?

Comment: Wow, was my question really that bad?  Or was it that obvious?  I'll just go ahead and make a fool of myself here... I really didn't know the answer until TheTXI so elegantly pointed it out.  In the spirit of "meta," I'd love to hear a comment on why my question is deserving of a down-vote.

Comment: I must say, I really enjoyed editing this question so late in its lifespan.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Does the question reflected in the URL change when a question title is edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2963/click-here-for-ponies)

Comment: I had to click twice before I realized the magic of MVC.

Comment: Then why didn't you make it Ponies?

Answer (score 5):

The ponies-free answer:

Yes, it does change. But the original URL still works – it doesn't link to the edits page it links straight to the most up-to-date version of the question. So the question has two equally valid URLs.