# ID field in the Hot Questions Atom feed changes over time

Tags: bug, feed, atom

The `atom:id` field of the [Hot Questions feed](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions) uses the URL of a question, including the [slugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug) which can change over time as it uses words from the question's title. With the current scheme, `<id>` changes when the title is edited. May I suggest changing it to use the canonical URL instead of [ponies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2963)?

I went through this [unofficial list of feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stack-exchange-and-its) and the Hot Questions seems to be the only one not using a canonical URL.

As a reference, [RFC 4287](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-4.2.6) says this:

> When an Atom Document is relocated, migrated, syndicated, republished, exported, or imported, the content of its atom:id element MUST NOT change.